# How can I disable "%20--disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity" from being automatically appended to the URL in Microsoft Edge(chromium)?

Tags: chromium, microsoft-edge

Since a few weeks ago, I've encountered this issue. When I click a URL in an text editor or in our instant messaging app on Windows 10, it invokes Microsoft Edge(Chromium) and `%20--disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity` is always automatically appended to the URL. Of course it fails with 404. For example, after I click `www.google.com`, the address bar has `https://www.google.com/%20--disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity`.

Besides, I've configured to use Microsoft Edge to view PDFs. Whenever I double-click a local PDF file, `%20--disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity` is automatically appended to the path in the address bar. It's quite annoying as I have to remove `%20--disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity` manually every time.

The non-Chromium Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 does not have this issue. My ME version is 88.0.705.29 beta (64 bit). The target field in ME shortcut property has the value `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\msedge.exe" --profile-directory=Default`. I searched `edge://flags/` and didn't find anything related to `RendererCodeIntegrity`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can it be caused by some add-on?

Comment: @harrymc thanks. I have only installed one add-on. After removing the add-on, the issue still exists.

Comment: What are the values of these registry keys: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\open\command` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\open\command`?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks. Both are `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\msedge.exe" --single-argument %1`.

Comment: These are the correct values. Something is injecting that command line switch. `--disable-features` is listed [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) among Chromium command line switches.

Comment: Does it happen when booting in [Safe Mode with Networking](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-start-windows-10-in-safe-mode-with-networking/)?

Comment: @harrymc It also happens in Safe Mode with Networking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset Microsoft Edge:

- Start *Settings > Apps > Apps & features*
- Click on "Microsoft Edge"
- Click the Modify button
- Allow execution and reboot.

If this still happens, try to enter the following command in PowerShell
that is Run as Administrator and reboot:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}
```

If the problem still happens, then it is caused by the applications you are using.
Try to find some pertinent configuration options in your text editor or in the
instant messaging app.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both methods and neither worked. BTW, the quotation marks in the command are not proper.

Comment: Fixed the quotation marks - the hazards of copy-paste. You could also try general troubleshooting: [sfc and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Or even [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) (which might be too heavy so check the apps first).

Comment: Does this work for macOS?

Comment: @Niing: This advice is for Windows.

Comment: On macos edge canary, I keep seeing this page is having a problem when browsing repositories on GitHub. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Niing: I suggest posting this as a new question (with full details).

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue. It's caused by third-party components in exploer.exe. Exploer.exe called edge with below command line:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --single-argument https://www.bing.com --disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity

Then Edge will add "%20--disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity" to the URL.

The third-party component is IP-Guard.